# How to mount each vue js component separately?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently I have a following structure:

```
import myComponent1 from 'my-component1/main.vue';
import myComponent2 from 'my-component2/main.vue';
new Vue({
    data() {

    },
    components: {
        'my-component1': myComponent1,
        'my-component1': myComponent2,

    },


}).$mount('body');
```

And into the HTML I use:

```
<my-component1></my-component1>....
```

It works. But mobile safari crushes if the page contains a lot of elements.
They suggest to use Vue only compile what is needed instead of the entire page. 
How can I compile each my component separately?

Comment: The safari issue https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4365

Comment: Why mount to the body?

Comment: Are you using anything to precompile your templates into render functions? Vueify should do that.